# How could I extract an array that's inside another array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with the following structure:

```
[["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"], ...]
```

How can I turn it into:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", ...]
```

And if there's a way, what's the fastest method of doing it since my array has about 100k elements?

I haven't tried any method yet since I'm a begginer and I've got no idea on how to do it.

Comment: Check out [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)